# Neo4j Linux 3.3.0 Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint

Tags: linux, neo4j

I trying to upgrade Neo4j to 3.3.0 version on Linux openSuse 42.3 machine. I downloaded and installed the Neo4j from the following tar file - Neo4j 3.3.0 (tar) from https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

but during startup I received the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint
```

I'm not sure but very likely `neo4j-community-3.3.0-unix.tar` archive have an issue and it is impossible to properly unpack it.

The SHA256 of `neo4j-community-3.3.0-unix.tar.gz` is **ED93502F1C83B465C21855AE2CB32D9C262722AB3B07017E57E147A8B4CF‌​5D06**

Please check it and provide a fix/solution how to install Neo4j 3.3.0

Comment: I have the same running on a mac and it starts and works fine

Comment: I'm unable to get it working.. something wrong with the archive. In opposite, I tried the 3.4.0-alpha01 and it was unpacked and started fine but I need exactly Neo4j 3.3.0.

Comment: What is the checksum on your 3.3 tar.gz? Maybe we have different ones or maybe your actual download is bad? the SHA256 checksum on my copy of `neo4j-community-3.3.0-unix.tar.gz` is `dbbc65683d65018c48fc14d82ee7691ca75f8f6ea79823b21291970638de5d88`

Comment: This is my SHA256 827CDAEBE27511773CA12957DBEEFD0A73A58614E4977BF3F535DE9AF383A3C3 I tested this on my Windows 10 machine also and 7z was unable to properly unpack it as well with some packaging error.

Comment: Sorry, it was SHA256 of the tar inside the tar.gz. The SHA256 of tar.gz is ED93502F1C83B465C21855AE2CB32D9C262722AB3B07017E57E147A8B4CF5D06 Separately downloaded on Windows and Linux and got the same SHA256

Comment: I have the same issue. How you solved that?

Comment: @ManoelVilela I found the previous archive with Neo4j 3.3.0, not the latest one

Comment: I have tried even with the 3.4.0-alpha02 version and the problem persists. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Running with "sudo" solved the issue. Looks like a permissions issue